# MySQL Table Update - How to avoid last_activity_date is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **Account a** with the **customers_id**, **account_id** and **last_activity_date** columns and another table **Transaction t** with transaction date **txn_date** column in my database. I want to update the **a.last_activity_date**  to be the **max(t.txn_date)**. Some customer accounts may not have txn_date from t. To avoid a null value in the updated **a.last_activity_date**, I have added a sub-inquiry using `WHERE EXISTS`. Here's the code:

```
UPDATE account a                                                           
SET a.last_activity_date =                                            
(SELECT MAX(t.txn_date）                                                  
 FROM transaction t                                                      
 WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id)                                      
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1                                                   
 FROM transaction t                                                      
 WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id);
```

But this sub-inquiry doesn't work:

> Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM transaction t WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id) WHERE
>   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FRO' at line 4.

Can someone help me with this please? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have your alias wrong. You need to add a from clause with the alias, like thi:

```
UPDATE a                                                           
SET last_activity_date =                                            
    (SELECT MAX(t.txn_date）                                                  
    FROM transaction t                                                      
    WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id
    )   
from account a                                   
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1                                                   
    FROM transaction t                                                      
    WHERE t.account_id = a.account_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks okay.  But a better way to express this in MySQL is to use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE account a JOIN
       (SELECT t.account_id, MAX(t.txn_date）as max_txn_date                                                  
        FROM transaction t  
        GROUP BY t.account_id
       ) t                                                    
       ON t.account_id = a.account_id)                                                        
    SET a.last_activity_date = t.max_txn_date;
```